# OpenWRT sending Pelco D Codes via SerialPort

Tags: serial-port, openwrt, pelco

I have an Linksys WRT54GL with a hacked serial port. I can use it normally via

```
echo "Test" > /dev/tts/1
```

and my Windows/Serial/Putty combo gets the data just fine.

I used [RS232 Analyser](http://www.commfront.com/RS232_Examples/CCTV/Pelco_D_Pelco_P_Examples_Tutorial.HTM) on a Windows machine to check my Pelco device and it works fine.

After some reading and installing I changed the serialport settings via stty to 2400 and checked it with putty.

Still fine with putty, but sending something like

```
echo "255,1,0,4,32,0,37," > /dev/tts/1
```

doesn't work. The Pelco device doesn't move.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is quite easy. The example from the documentary:

> Suppose you are controlling camera 1 (address 1) to pan left at high speed, the command string of the first 6 bytes would be: `FF 01 00 04 3F 00`

The command in linux:

```
echo -e -n "\xFF\x01\x00\x04\x3F\x00" > /dev/tts/1
```

the manpage tells us that:

```
-e enable interpretation of backslash escapes
-n do not output the trailing newline
```

and it works.